# PHP ODBC connect not connecting to Sybase db

Tags: php, odbc, sybase-asa

I set up a web site using PHP to talk to a Sybase db (already in use for a in-house application) via an ODBC connection, so users in the field could access the in-house db. This was on a 2003 NT server, and everything worked fine.

Then I set up a similar site on an XP Pro machine (this time, by myself), and while the web site is accessible, and the PHP programming works, the PHP pages cannot access the db. I get no errors, I've checked `phpinfo` between the two sites (working and non-working) and have come up with no ideas.

Convinced the connect to database via ODBC not working, should the configuration on an XP Pro be different than from a 2003 NT machine? ODBC is set up the same way on both machines.

```
<?php
$Page_Name = "apptlist1.php";
import_request_variables('gpc');

$db_host = "wintermlocal";
$db_server_name = "winpest";
$db_name = "windata.db";
$db_file = "c:\data\windata.db";
$db_conn_name = "php_script";
$db_user = "dba";
$db_pass = "sql";
//================================================================
$connect_string = "Driver={Adaptive Server Anywhere 7.0};"
    ."CommLinks=tcpip(Host=$db_host);"
    ."ServerName=$db_server_name;"
    ."DatabaseName=$db_name;"
    ."DatabaseFile=$db_file;"
    ."ConnectionName=$db_conn_name;"
    ."uid=$db_user;pwd=$db_pass";
//================================================================

$connect = odbc_connect($connect_string,'','');
?>
```

> Warning: odbc_connect() [function.odbc-connect]:
>
> SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>
> Data source name not found and no default driver specified
>
> SQL state IM002 in SQLConnect in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\allpro\apptlist1.php on line 22

Comment: Do you have the driver for the DB type?

Comment: Set up odbc connection to sybase (successfully) in odbc administrator, then using php odbc connect to take advantage of that.

Comment: I appreciate your looking at this, I'd be happy to discuss it in detail, I am really on the hook for this. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the item with some code, as requested.

Comment: The error IM002 points to ServerName (winpest) being an incorrect system data source name, while you were expecting it, I guess, to be the name declared in/by the ASA server. Can you try using the alternative form of the ASA connection parameters: ENG instead of ServerName?

Comment: Did you explicitly change the "database name" in the ASA service definition (assuming dbsrv7 is actually running as a service)?
For a database file windata.db, the default database name would be "windata" not "windata.db" as used in $db_name.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying that $doresult is 0, but in fact the problem is that $connect is 0, correct?

It could be the protections on the .db file.

Is the database already run by some ASA service engine (which would define server=winpest, dbname=windata) or do you expect the PHP script to start the engine if needed?
In that case, I often had problems around the database engine (dbeng7) not being in the system path, which prevents the ODBC driver from starting the engine database on request.

Comment: Actually using the multi-user program, dbsrv7.exe instead of dbeng7.exe. Do you mean that the program 'dbserv7.exe' should be on the path, not just the directory it's in? 
Also, for a permission problem, I've updated the folder in which the database file is, or should I be doing something with User Accounts?

Comment: No, as usual, it's just the name of the directory of dbsrv7.exe which needs to be in PATH, not "dbsrv7.exe" itself.

Comment: I double-checked the pathway, tried setting ENG variable, looked at the permissions on the web file folder...still not working.